# how to swap the value for initial number and ending number?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this program:

```
print('Python accept decrease numbers\n')

initial = int(input('Initial number:'))
ending = int(input('Ending number:'))
decrease = -(int(input('Decrease number:')))

for n in range(initial,ending,decrease):
    if (initial < ending):
        ending,initial = initial,ending
    print (n)
```

I want to swap the initial and the ending value if the initial is smaller than the ending value so that I can get a decrease value
instead, it print out nothing:

```
Python accept decrease numbers

Initial number:5
Ending number:50
Decrease number:2
>>>
```

is it i missed out something?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the check outside the `for` cycle:

```
print('Python accept decrease numbers\n')

initial = int(input('Initial number:'))
ending = int(input('Ending number:'))
decrease = -(int(input('Decrease number:')))

if (initial < ending):
    ending,initial = initial,ending

for n in range(initial,ending,decrease):
    print (n)
```